# Linq Query to fetch data using non entity object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to fetch the record from 3 tables by comparing the user Logged in name

Here is my code:

```
 public ActionResult MeritList() //departmental merit listed students details with status 1 
    {
        var username= HttpContext.Session["UserName"];
        List<StdListModel> model = new List<StdListModel>();
        var query = (from s in Context.tblStdDetails
                     join e in Context.tblStdEnrollments on s.ID equals e.StdReg_ref_id 
                     //join d in Context.tblDepartments on e.Depart_ref_id equals d.ID
                     where s.Status == '1' && e.tblDepartment.DepartName == username
                     select new StdListModel
                     {
                         ID = s.ID,
                         Name = s.Name,
                         FatherName = s.FatherName,
                         CNIC = s.CNIC,
                         FormNo = s.FormNo,
                         DiaryNo = s.DiaryNo,
                         Status = s.Status
                     }).ToList();
        foreach(var item in query)
        {
            model.Add(new StdListModel()
            {
                ID=item.ID,
                Name=item.Name,
                FatherName=item.FatherName,
                CNIC=item.CNIC,
                FormNo=item.FormNo,
                DiaryNo=item.DiaryNo

            });
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Also Tried this Query

```
var query = (from s in Context.tblStdDetails
                     join e in Context.tblStdEnrollments on s.ID equals e.StdReg_ref_id 
                     join d in Context.tblDepartments on e.Depart_ref_id equals d.ID
                     where s.Status == '1' && d.DepartName.Equals(username)
                     select new StdListModel
                     {
                         ID = s.ID,
                         Name = s.Name,
                         FatherName = s.FatherName,
                         CNIC = s.CNIC,
                         FormNo = s.FormNo,
                         DiaryNo = s.DiaryNo,
                         Status = s.Status
                     }).ToList();
```

But it does not return anything model=0, query =0, the database has right values and I don't get any error either.

Comment: Is query contains any value?

Comment: No, query=0 also there is no error in this query. The database has right value as well.

Comment: I think query is correct, you got the exact user name? check all values which is coming or not

Comment: Are you sure you want to compare a username to the name of a department? `e.tblDepartment.DepartName == username`

Comment: Yes, the username is exactly the same and in the query also.

Comment: @Marco yup I need to fetch student data of relevant department login only

Comment: kindly check my updated post I have added another query which I tried also but got the same result

Comment: If you use joins in an ORM you are doing it wrong. You should define *relations* and navigation properties in your *entities* and simply load the matching enrollments. The very fact that you named your *entities* with table prefixes is a very strong smell

Comment: PS: You don't need to call `ToList()` unless you intend to reuse the list. `foreach` is enough to execute the queryable and enumerate the results

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos entities have relationships and also have navigation properties.

Comment: @lilli why do you use joins then?

Comment: @lilli are you sure there *are* any results to return? Have you checked the generated query? Does it return any results? Do you really want to match `username` with `DepartmentName` ? Is `Status` a Char or an int?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos kindly guide me how can I fetch data without using joins with conditions based on different tables.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes I have one student data with status (INT)  =1. I need to fetch only those students who are enrolled in that logged in username department like ''IT"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem. It is in

```
s.Status == '1'
```

I just changed it into

```
s.Status == 1
```

and it works fetch the data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

please check username with tolower() and trim function.

```
e.tblDepartment.DepartName.ToLower().Trim() == username.ToLower().Trim()
or
e.tblDepartment.DepartName.ToLower().Trim().equals(username.ToLower().Trim())
```

Comment: username object doesn't have the property for ToLower().Trim().

Comment: please try to convert it in string...i.e  username.ToString().ToLower().Trim();

Comment: I got this error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method"

Comment: please change 
var username= HttpContext.Session["UserName"].ToString();
instead of
var username= HttpContext.Session["UserName"];

and 

username.ToLower().Trim(); instead of
username.ToString().ToLower().Trim();

Comment: Still not getting any result

Comment: please try with removing this line **s.Status == '1'**...seems like your status is not matching with results

Comment: I have tried by removing s.status than e.tblDepartment.DepartName == username condition but still don't get any result, but when I run this query in SQL server it returns 1 record.

Comment: does your Context.tblStdDetails returns any data ?

i.e please debug context.tblStdDetails.

var data=from data in context.tblStdDetails select data;

Comment: when it try this query var query = (from data in Context.tblStdDetails where data.Status == '1' select data); it does not return

Comment: use **where data.status=='1'** if status is of **char type** and use **data.status=="1"** if its a **string** type